# Pulling from a Mercurial repository over ssh with non-default ports

Tags: ssh, mercurial, hg

I'm trying to pull changes from a server which has sshd on port 2345 and an hg server listening locally on port 5432. I already have certifcate-based authentication for ssh, so there no need for a password.

This **doesn't work**:

```
hg -v pull ssh://me@myserver.com:2345/ -p 5432
```

since the pull command apparently takes the port number from where I assumed ssh would be taking it...

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing would be to put an entry in `~/.ssh/config`, something like:

```
Host myserver.com
Port 2345
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need

```
hg -v pull ssh://me@myserver.com:2345/full_pathname
```

eg.

```
hg -v pull ssh://me@myserver.com:2345//srv/hg/username/repos
```

-p is not a recognized option for hg pull. Note your path syntax above is also wrong

```
hg -v pull ssh://me@myserver.com:2345/
```

is not correct syntax.